# android: use Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED or ...?

Tags: android, android-manifest, bootcompleted

In the AndroidManifest file, I want to capture the BOOT_COMPLETED event when the user re-boots their device.  I am adding this permission:

"uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"

I have seen two "intent-filters" used by others on Stackoverflow:

"Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" and

"android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"

What is the preferred action string here?  Please advise and explain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED == android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`

They're both the same, because if you look into what the value of `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` is, you'll see that it's `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.

Typically in the Manifest, you'll use `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` due to `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` being Java code rather than xml.

But in your code, you can use `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` as an alternative due to it being much easier to remember.

Answer (score -3):

Here is a complete solution:

Set the permission in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

You need a receiver to run when your system restarts so something like this:

```
public class StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
           // everything here executes after system restart
        }
    }
}
```

Include this receiver in your manifest like below:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".service.StartMyActivityAtBootReceiver"
    android:label="StartMyServiceAtBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```