# how to receive the boot completed broadcast in my react-native app?

Tags: android, react-native, bootcompleted

I want my `rn` app autostart when boot up, but it seems that my app cannot receive the boot completed broadcast. Is there anything wrong with my code?

I've already add all the user permissions(uses-permission and action), and make sure my apk not in sdcard, not in stopped state...

here is my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.rnproject"
  android:installLocation="internalOnly"
  android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
  >

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

  <application>
    <activity
      android:name=".MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    <receiver
      android:name=".com.rnproject.BootBroadcastReceiver" 
      android:enabled="true" 
      android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>  
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED"/>
            <data android:scheme="file">
            </data>
        </intent-filter>        
    </receiver>   
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**BootBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
package com.rnproject; 

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;  

import android.content.Context;  

import android.content.Intent;  

import android.util.Log;

public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    static final String ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("BootBroadcastReceiver", intent.getAction()); 

        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION)) {    
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);    

            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            context.startActivity(activityIntent);
        }    
    }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.rnproject;

public class MainActivity {

  public static void main(String[], args) {

    System.out.print("HelloWorld");

  } 

}
```

I expect my app can receive the system broadcast, if you can serve my problem, thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51295092/2078074). May be it helps

Comment: @Dhruv thx! I solved it : degrade the sdk version from 27 to 25, and it works! amazing!